# Not able to understand use of ch = cin.get()

Tags: c++, cin

In this program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int SIZE=4;
   char Sentence[SIZE];

   cout << "Enter the sentence" <<endl;
   cin >> Sentence;
  
   cout << "\n The string read with cin was"
 << endl <<Sentence <<endl;

  char ch = cin.get();
}
```

I am unable to understand that we are using `ch =cin.get()`  after  `cout << "\n The string read with cin was" << endl <<Sentence <<endl;` so why in output I am getting only the first character of stream . I should get the whole input sentence as I have used ch=cin.get() at last so it should not have any effect.
can anyone explain me this ?

Comment: You'll get the "whole sentence" only if it is 3 chars or less with no whitespace

Answer (score 0):

Because char takes only 1 character ;-) So you assign cin.get() to char and you have 1 character as a result :-)